# Problema de formatação do site

Tags: css, html5

Um site teste que criei está com espaçamentos enormes, não faço ideia de como resolver isso, não está nem um pouco responsivo. O problema está relacionado provavelmente com o HTML e o CSS do site. Segue ambos abaixo (são códigos pequenos). Segue o repositorio do github onde o site está hospedado: https://github.com/aulasdelivery/aulasdelivery.github.io e este é o link do mesmo: https://aulasdelivery.github.io/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Aulas Delivery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mavi.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icon.png">
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>

            <div class="container">
            <img id="coruja" src="img/coruja.png" alt="coruja">
            </div>

            <div class="header-black">
            </div>

            <div class="container">

                    <nav id="menu" class="pull-left">
                        <li>Aulas Delivery - Reforço Escolar</li>
                    </nav>
            </div>
        </header>

        <section>
            <div class="info1">
                <img id="info1" src="img/livro.png" alt="livro">
                <p>Aulas independentes ou reforço escolar (plano mensal)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="info2">
                <img id="info2" src="img/gongo.png" alt="relogio">
                <p>Aulas independentes ou reforço escolar (plano mensal)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="info3">
                <img id="info3" src="img/mochila.png" alt="aviao-papel">
                <p>Aulas na casa do aluno (dependendo do local)</p>
            </div>
            <div id="materias">
                <img src="img/materias.jpg" alt="materias">
            </div>
            <div id="imagemPerfil">
                <img src="img/mavi.jpg" alt="mavi">
                <h3>Maria Victoria Cabral</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="estrela1">
                <img src="img/estrela.png" alt="estrela">
                <h4>Estudante de Direito da Universidade Católica de Salvador.</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="estrela2">
                <img src="img/estrela.png" alt="estrela">
                <h4>Melhor professora!</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="estrela3">
                <img src="img/estrela.png" alt="estrela">
                <h4>Melhor professora!</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="contato">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <ul><span>Contato -</span>
                            <li><h4>Celular - (71) 983485225</h4></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/mariavictoria.cabral.3">Facebook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/mariavictoria.cabral.3">Instagram</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <ul><span>Biografia de aulas -</span>
                            <li><p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p></li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </section>

        <script src = "lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face{

    font-family: 'IndieFlower';
    src: url("../fonts/IndieFlower.ttf");
    font-size: 1em;
}

header {

    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #FF9F80; 
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
header .container {
    position: relative;

}

header .header-black {
    background-color: #FFC48C;
    height: 30px;

}


header #coruja {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
}

#menu{
    margin: 30px 140px;
}
#menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "IndieFlower";
    color: #0B486B;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0px 25px;
}
section{

background-color: #9DE0AD;
height: 1200px;
}
section .info1{

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 420px;
    left: -820px;
}
section .info1 p{

    font-size: 16px;
    color: #490A3D;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'IndieFlower';
    font-weight: bold;
}section .info2{

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 420px;
    left: 24px;
}
section .info2 p{

    font-size: 16px;
    color: #490A3D;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'IndieFlower';
    font-weight: bold;
}
section .info3{

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 420px;
    left: 24px;
}
section .info3 p{

    font-size: 16px;
    color: #490A3D;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'IndieFlower';
    font-weight: bold;
}
#materias{

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
    right: -830px;
}
#imagemPerfil{
[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: -570px;
    right: -50px;
}
#imagemPerfil h3{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #490A3D;
    font-family: 'IndieFlower';
    font-weight: bold;
}
#estrela1{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: -915px;
    right: -365px;
}
#estrela1 h4{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #490A3D;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'IndieFlower';
    font-weight: bold;
}
#estrela2{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: -905px;
    right: -365px;
}
#estrela2 h4{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #490A3D;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'IndieFlower';
    font-weight: bold;
}
#estrela3{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: -895px;
    right: -365px;
}
#estrela3 h4{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #490A3D;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'IndieFlower';
    font-weight: bold;
}
#contato{
    background-color: #5E299A;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
#contato ul{
    margin-top: 36px;
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
}
#contato ul span{
    color: #FDE092;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#contato li a{
    font-size: 19px;
}
#contato li h4{
    color: #FDE092;
    font-size: 19px;
}
#contato p{
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #FDE092;
}
```

Comment: Então, pelo entendi da sua pergunta, tem que ver o que esta acontecendo com as semânticas pois você já tem o bootstrap, tenta ver se ele esta funcionando o bootstrap e veja a documentação dele também, em questão de colocar container e row. Talvez isso seja o problema do site estar todo desalinhado.

Comment: @Nathan eu retirei o container e o row, e no console não especifica nada se o bootstrap não está funcionando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu reescrevi algumas coisas de seu código, confere se está ok pra você.

**CSS**

```
    @font-face{
        font-family: 'IndieFlower';
        src: url("../fonts/IndieFlower.ttf");
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 130px;
        background-color: #FF9F80; 
        z-index: 2;
        position: relative;

    }
    header .container {
        position: relative;

    }
    header .header-black {
        background-color: #FFC48C;
        height: 30px;

    }
    header #coruja {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1px;
        left: 40px;
    }
    #menu{
        margin: 30px 140px;

    }
    #menu li{
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: "IndieFlower";
        color: #0B486B;
        font-size: 30px;
        padding: 0px 40px;
    }
    ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-left: -40px;
    }

    ul li{
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 6px 0;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .img-icon{
        float: left;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    #professora h3{
        font-size: 24px;
        color: #490A3D;
        font-family: 'IndieFlower';
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #professora h4{
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #490A3D;
        font-family: 'IndieFlower';
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .margin-top-20{
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .margin-top-30{
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .margin-top-40{
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    section{
        background-color: #9DE0AD;
        height: auto;
    }

    #competencias p{
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #490A3D;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'IndieFlower';
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 30px
    }

    .padding-left-40{
        padding-left: 40px;
    }

    .padding-left-50{
        padding-left: 50px;
    }

    .padding-left-60{
        padding-left: 60px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        /*Configure seu mobile aqui */
    }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Aulas Delivery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://aulasdelivery.github.io/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://aulasdelivery.github.io/img/icon.png">
</head>
<body>

    <header>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <img id="coruja" src="https://aulasdelivery.github.io/img/coruja.png" alt="coruja">
        </div>

        <div class="header-black">
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <nav id="menu" class="pull-left">
                <li>Aulas Delivery - Reforço Escolar</li>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="professora">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row margin-top-20">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://aulasdelivery.github.io/img/mavi.jpg" alt="mavi">
                        <h3>Maria Victoria Cabral</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <ul id="stars">
                            <li>
                                <img class="img-icon" src="https://aulasdelivery.github.io/img/estrela.png" alt="estrela">
                                <h4>Estudante de Direito da Universidade Católica de Salvador.</h4>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img class="img-icon" src="https://aulasdelivery.github.io/img/estrela.png" alt="estrela">
                                <h4>Melhor professora!</h4>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img class="img-icon" src="https://aulasdelivery.github.io/img/estrela.png" alt="estrela">
                                <h4>Melhor professora!</h4>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img class="img-icon" src="https://aulasdelivery.github.io/img/estrela.png" alt="estrela">
                                <h4>Melhor professora!</h4>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img class="img-icon" src="https://aulasdelivery.github.io/img/estrela.png" alt="estrela">
                                <h4>Melhor professora!</h4>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img class="pull-right img-responsive" src="https://aulasdelivery.github.io/img/materias.jpg" alt="materias">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="competencias">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row padding-left-60 margin-top-40">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div>
                        <img class="img-icon" src="https://aulasdelivery.github.io/img/livro.png" alt="livro">
                        <p>Aulas independentes ou reforço escolar (plano mensal)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div>
                        <img class="img-icon" src="https://aulasdelivery.github.io/img/gongo.png" alt="relogio">
                        <p>Aulas independentes ou reforço escolar (plano mensal)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row padding-left-60 margin-top-40">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div>
                        <img class="img-icon" src="https://aulasdelivery.github.io/img/mochila.png" alt="aviao-papel">
                        <p>Aulas na casa do aluno (dependendo do local)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div>
                        <img class="img-icon" src="https://aulasdelivery.github.io/img/mochila.png" alt="aviao-papel">
                        <p>Aulas na casa do aluno (dependendo do local)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="contato">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row margin-top-40">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                            <p>
                                <h4>Celular - (71) 983485225</h4>
                            </p>
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/mariavictoria.cabral.3">Facebook</a> - 
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/mariavictoria.cabral.3">Instagram</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row margin-top-20">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <span>Biografia de aulas - 2017 - Todos os direitos reservados</span>
                            <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

    <script src = "https://aulasdelivery.github.io/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://aulasdelivery.github.io/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Obs.:** Como pode ver todas as imagens e inclusões de scripts eu add o endereço absoluto de seu site, fiz isso pra poder testar aqui na minha máquina, só remover conforme desejar.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, desculpe colocar como resposta pode ser que não seja isso, tentei fazer no jsfidle mas você não limitou o tamanho das imagens então continuou com o layout quebrado, mas vamos lá, encontrei alguns erros no código, pode ser que seja isso
as tags  não estão sendo fechadas, repare, irei marcar no código pode não ser isso mas desculpe não comentar, ainda não tenho pontos suficientes... Outra coisa reparei que você repete muito código por exemplo info1, info2, info3 p seria melhor você criar uma class ao invés de id e ali não sei se seria realmente necessario criar uma div para cada um na parte das estrelas, poderia ser feito com ul e li mesmo mas isso fica ao seu critério, deixei quebrado a parte do codigo para destacar a ul que falta, veja se é isso e repito, desculpe por não comentar

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Aulas Delivery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mavi.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icon.png">
</head>
<body>

    <header>

        <div class="container">
        <img id="coruja" src="img/coruja.png" alt="coruja">
        </div>

        <div class="header-black">
        </div>

        <div class="container">

                <nav id="menu" class="pull-left">
                    <li>Aulas Delivery - Reforço Escolar</li>
                </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section>
        <div class="info1">
            <img id="info1" src="img/livro.png" alt="livro">
            <p>Aulas independentes ou reforço escolar (plano mensal)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info2">
            <img id="info2" src="img/gongo.png" alt="relogio">
            <p>Aulas independentes ou reforço escolar (plano mensal)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info3">
            <img id="info3" src="img/mochila.png" alt="aviao-papel">
            <p>Aulas na casa do aluno (dependendo do local)</p>
        </div>
        <div id="materias">
            <img src="img/materias.jpg" alt="materias">
        </div>
        <div id="imagemPerfil">
            <img src="img/mavi.jpg" alt="mavi">
            <h3>Maria Victoria Cabral</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="estrela1">
            <img src="img/estrela.png" alt="estrela">
            <h4>Estudante de Direito da Universidade Católica de Salvador.</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="estrela2">
            <img src="img/estrela.png" alt="estrela">
            <h4>Melhor professora!</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="estrela3">
            <img src="img/estrela.png" alt="estrela">
            <h4>Melhor professora!</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="contato">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <ul><span>Contato -</span>
                        <li><h4>Celular - (71) 983485225</h4></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/mariavictoria.cabral.3">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/mariavictoria.cabral.3">Instagram</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">


                         <ul><span>Biografia de aulas -</span>
                            <li><p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p></li>
                        </ul> <--- AQUI FALTA FECHAR A UL
```

```
        </div>

    </section>

    <script src = "lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: para limitar as imagens adicione no css: img{width: 100%}

Comment: @BrunoCastro não funcionou

Comment: @AndersonHenrique não funcionou

Comment: @GuilhermePassos poderia mandar um print de como está a tela fazendo um favor?